# Japanese readers/speakers of Fairy Tail: What's Lucy's current age?

Tags: fairy-tail

I was wondering this about the term Bishojo. So about the 美少女? , I was curious on some points. I read Fairy Tail and there is one character(Lucy) whose 17 at the start and time passes and when it ends I believe their age is 20 or so.

So I've seen figures of them here released after the series ends and they use the word Bishojo:

https://hobby.dengeki.com/news/1009509/

and here about them:

https://animemiru.jp/articles/22620/

So I was wondering does it mean the character is not 20 and I was wrong about their age and all

Comment: Are you familiar with the "eternal present" trope? Consider Urusei Yatsura: Ataru is 17 at the start of the show and so is Lum. If you were to count all the Christmas / Beach/ Birthday episode and try to argue how many years must have passed... they would probably be at least 35 by the serie end... Instead they are still 17.

Comment: Is the question about whether or not the characters actually age in the show? Or is the question about the applicability of the term "bishoujo" instead?

Comment: There is little question about her age, because the author introduced an in-world calendar system. Chapter 1 is dated year X784, and chapter 545 is dated X793. Likewise, Lucy's age in the early portion of the story is written in a cover panel, and it's 17. So Lucy is roughly 26 by the end of Fairy Tail. Lucy was frozen in time from "16th December X784" to some time "in X791". In-world they refer to this period as "7 years", but it's manifestly less than that. So you may remove 6.5 years in matters of physical aging.

Answer (score 0):

Bishoujo means a young and beautiful girl. 美(Bi) Means "beauty" and 少女(Shoujo) means "girl". This term is used for girls between 13~ and 20~ years old. The masculine of Bishoujo would be Bishounen. So, using this term means referring to a pretty girl, with cute manners.

Comment: so she can be 20 and be called that?

Comment: Zain, exactly. Since this term is only used for young girls. 20 is too young an age to be considered an old woman.